# Keep quotation marks in a formatted list Racket

Tags: list, racket, format-string

How do you print a formatted string with quotation marks, and without the backward slashes?

For example, when I enter

```
(format "say ~a" "hello there!")
```

I want to get

```
" say "hello there!" "
```

I want the quotation marks wrapped around "hello there" as the way I typed in. However, if I format it as a string, it turns out like this:

```
"say \"hello there!\""
```

Is there a way to keep the quotation marks without having the backward slash?

Answer (score 1):

evaluating *strings*, and [`print`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._print)))/[`println`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#(def._((lib._racket/private/misc..rkt)._println))) print the quote `"` as`\"`.

Maybe you're looking for [`display`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._display)))/[`displayln`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#(def._((lib._racket/private/misc..rkt)._displayln))):

```
(displayln (format "say \"~a\"" "hello there!"))
; => say "hello there!"
```

Comment: or `(displayln (format "say ~v" "hello there!"))`... using `\"~a\"` in a format string is an anti-pattern that should be replaced with `~v`

Comment: Correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `~s` instead of `~a`

```
> (format "say ~s" "hello there!")`
"say \"hello there!\""
```